# expand/collapse have one row show while the others are hidden

Tags: javascript, expand, cognos, cognos-10

this is in a cognos list.
So I know a lot of JS but obviously not enough to figure this out. I have a list, and in that list I have a hierarchy going that will expand several layers in. I want all layers to start hidden but the first layer. So something like this

first layer (shown)
                          second layer(hidden)
                                                        third layer(hidden)

My JS code is below and for the life of me I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function StartHidden() {
   var q=document.getElementById("ExpandedTable");

   // get the table
   tbl = q.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
   var isFirstRow=true;

   for ( var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
          var trCurrent = tbl.rows; // the current row
          var d = trCurrent.cells[0]; // first cell
          var c = d.firstChild;

          if (i < 2 || c.tagName.indexOf("IMG") != -1) {
                 c = c.src; // leave it visible, since it has + icon
for ( var j = 1; j < trCurrent.cells.length; j++) {
   trCurrent.cells[j].width="1"; 
}
          }
          else {
                 trCurrent.style.display = "none"; // hide the row
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain the current behavior. What are you experiencing with this code? Even without context the line that sticks out at me is 'c = c.src'. The variable c was previously assigned a DOM element (d.firstChild). This line seems to be changing c to a string representation of the 'src' attribute of the object itself. In effect the c variable will no longer store a reference to a DOM object but will instead contain a string. I can't see how this would serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with Cognos Javascript objects within a report, you'll have to use the getFormWarpRequest function, instead of working with document object directly. 
The right code snippet should be:

```
var fW = (typeof getFormWarpRequest == "function" ?getFormWarpRequest() : document.forms["formWarpRequest"]);
// if it’s undefined, check if it is running in a portlet
if ( !fW || fW == undefined) { fW = ( formWarpRequest_THIS_ ?formWarpRequest_THIS_ : formWarpRequest_NS_ );}
```

However this is only part of the solution, since from Cognos 8.4, the data objects (list, crosstabs), are generated with dynamic names and IDS. 
Therefore you should use getElementsByTagName method instead of getElementById.
An example can be found in here:
[Ironside - IBM Cognos and JavaScript – Part II](https://www.ironsidegroup.com/2011/09/27/ibm-cognos-and-javascript-%E2%80%93-part-ii/) 
Additional trick that can ease the work would be working with jQuery within Cognos. Very well documented in here: 
[Dynamic reporting in Cognos using jQuery](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-pp-reporting-advanced-report-design-page647/) 
And an example I wrote in here: 
[Dynamic custom exception in Cognos using jQuery](http://jquerycognosintegration.blogspot.com) 
Additional Cognos documentation regarding working with javascript can be found in here: 
[Cognos - Upgrading JavaScript Applications](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021973)

Comment: If you are working in version 10.2 or later you should use the Cognos JavaScript API which makes wokring with JS much easier: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.0.doc/c_prmpt_api_overview.html